# How can I exclude a peer dependency from ng update?

Tags: angular, package, node-modules

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Angular 7 to 8. When running `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`, I get the following error:

`Package "@swimlane/ngx-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.8.26", would install "0.9.1").`

Is there a way to exclude zone.js from my ng update? It's already on 0.8.26.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ng update will update the zone.js for version 0.9.1, not 0.8.26. That's the current version (read the error message carefully).

The issue is with the npm package '@swimlane/ngx-charts', the current version requires zone.js version ^0.8.26, and the update will install the 0.9.1 version, which is not compatible with the current version of the package.

Simply uninstall and install the package:

```
npm uninstall @swimlane/ngx-charts
npm install @swimlane/ngx-charts
```